# Excessive memory use and CPU load when using Banner and Interstitial Ads

Tags: android, memory-management, cpu-usage, interstitial, banner-ads

**Memory**

When running my app and and looking at it's memory usage it uses around **20MB**

When I enable my banner ads, the memory usage starts at about **28MB** and moves to around **50MB**.

On enabling my interstitial ads, memory usage approaches **80MB**.

**CPU Load as view in Eclipse DDMS (System Information tab)**

in Eclipse, if I look at the CPU load, without ads, it's around **20%**

With Ads enabled (Both banners and interstitials), CPU usage goes up to around **36%**

I would like to know from more experienced developers if this is normal - I would expect memory and CPU usage to increase, but I find this excessive.

Comment: Are you seeing this just on the emulator or even on a real device. The memory addition doesnt seem to be too high. 8megabytes is negligible. I've only used iAds and they tend to pull in about 5 mb each time and cache it. This way, when the timer is up, they switch to the otherone. who are you doing your ads through?

Comment: Hi @Cripto, I'm using the MobFox SDK with MobFox as my primary network and AdMob as my secondary.  I'm using a real device (Nexus 10 tablet).  It's worrying because after every launch the memory usage jumps up, not sure if it's a leak or not though because I think (although I can't be sure at the moment), it tops out at about 82MB.  Cheers!